# Copy one slide from a google presentation into a new google presentation using API

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-drive-api, google-slides, google-slides-api

Is it possible to copy inside an empty Google Presentation some slides from another Google Presentation using Google API?

Comment: @pinoyyid is correct, this isn't currently supported. Please file a feature request at the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?labels=Type-Enhancement,API-Slides) with a little more detail about your usecase so it can be can considered for a future enhancement.

Comment: As mentioned by Eric Koleda in this related [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33494863/copy-one-slide-from-google-presentation-into-a-new-google-presentation-using-api/40530607#40530607), you can read the slide from the source presentation and then attempt to replicate it in the destination presentation using [Google Slides API](https://developers.google.com/slides/). However, please note that at the moment not all Slides features are supported in the API.